# How do I format stringbuilder to send my emails in tables rather then just plain text

Tags: c#, email

So I have a page where the users fill out a comments / request form and when the press submit all of the information they fill out gets sent right to my email.

I am trying to make it so when the email comes through it is easier to read and in tables or html.  How do I do this?

Here is my code:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendFormat("Request Name:  {0}, <b><b/>  <br/><br/>",   txtBugName.Text.Trim());
            sb.AppendFormat("Category: {0}<br/><br/>", ddlModule.SelectedValue);
            sb.AppendFormat("Sub-Category: {0}<br/><br/>", ddlPage.SelectedValue);
            sb.AppendFormat("Description: {0}<br/><br/>", txtComments.Text.Trim());
            sb.AppendFormat("Email is: {0}<br/><br/>", txtemail.Text.Trim());
```

What do I need to add to change the format?

Comment: Remove the <br /> tags and put in the right html tags (<table>, <tr>, <td>) to create a table?

Comment: This is what I am looking for thank you.  I am knew to programming this is the first website I am making so i do not have to much experience with tables.  Could you give me an example of one line of the table?

Comment: --Edit-- See answer below. It's pretty basic HTML knowledge. By setting <table> </table> you create a table. Inside that you make a <tr></tr> (TableRow) and inside your row make <td></td> (TableCell, can't remember what the D is for). So a valid table would be <table><tr><td>Row 0, Cell 0</td><td>Row 0, Cell 1</td></tr><tr><td>Row 1, Cell 0</td><td>Row 1, Cell 1</td></tr></table>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should look more like:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table>");
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Request Name:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", txtBugName.Text.Trim());
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Category:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", ddlModule.SelectedValue);
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Sub-Category:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", ddlPage.SelectedValue);
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Description:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", txtComments.Text.Trim());
sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>Email is:</td><td>{0}</td></tr>", txtemail.Text.Trim());
sb.Append("<table>");
```

Then I'm assuming the `IsBodyHtml` property is true, since you were using HTML already

Comment: Yes the IsBodyHTML is on true thank you.  One last question is it possible to make each row of the table a different color.  For example first row greyish second row blueish third row grey ish just so I can distinguish the rows better in the email?

Comment: Sure, in it's simplest form just add a style attribute to your <tr> tag like <tr style = "background-color: lightgrey;"> and do it for each odd/even row. It's not very dynamic but it works. Again, this is very basic HTML/CSS knowledge. I suggest you Google for some tutorials on it. It ain't so hard :-)

Comment: Thank you google has been the best the last few weeks.  I just recently found this website and really love the community.

Answer (score 2):

You would set the `MailMessage`'s `IsBodyHtml` property to true:

```
var message = new MailMessage();

message.IsBodyHtml = true;

message.Body = "your html snippet";
```

[System.Net.Mail.MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, but from there how would I get the request name, category, subcategory ... Into individual rows of a table?  How would I do that?

Comment: @user1486774 you're telling me you don't know how to build an HTML table?!